# Modify Lazy adapter to get specific Image

Tags: android, android-gridview, lazylist

I am fetching image from remote server using a [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) in a grid view . **I am trying to modify my gridview to a clickable gridview which view the downloaded image in fullscreen with specific position.**
Images are being cached on SD card and in memory with [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList).I wanted to get the image by position of url

Here is my code but i still don't get it to work .Any helps would be greatly appreciated!

this is my OnItemClicklistener in grid view

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
     // Sending image position to FullScreenActivity
         Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), FullImageActivity.class);
         // passing array index
         i.putExtra("string", pathA);
         i.putExtra("position", position);
         startActivity(i);
}
```

here is What i call to get specific image to view in fullscreen activity.I don't really understand how to call image with position using the same adapter

```
    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image position
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    String[] d = i.getStringArrayExtra("string");
    LazyAdapter imageAdapter = new LazyAdapter(this, d);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.d[position]);
```

Here is part of my adapter that i used
    public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
    private Activity activity;
    public String[] data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], image);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tons of trying i finally get it to work , hope its help others

In the fullscreenactitivty.java

```
    // get intent data
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // Selected image url with position
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("position");
    String[] d = i.getStringArrayExtra("string");
    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplication());
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(d[position], imageView);
```